# How to deserialize JSON from MVC using JQuery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

Ok, its late Friday afternoon, and I've been fighting this for way too long... I have an MVC2 class that returns a JSON. JQuery throws an error when trying to deserialize it in the browser.

Here's the controller:

```
<HttpPost()>
Function ChangeAddress(ByVal addressId As Integer) As ActionResult

    ' Build and return JSON containing address.
    Dim v As New TestViewModel With {.Address1 = "My House"}
    Return Json(v)

End Function
```

Here's the view model:

```
Public Class TestViewModel

    Public Property Address1 As String

End Class
```

And here's the script:

```
// If list is not empty and item was found...
if (found == true) {

         var sum = 14;

    // Get fields of newly selected address.
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../Checkout/ChangeAddress',
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
             data: { addressId: sum },
        success: function (result) {

            var json = result.get_data();
            var data = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);

            alert("Success!");

        }
    });
};
```

The deserialization code is from the MVC Music Store example. When executed, JQuery throws an exception on get_data, saying "Object doesn't support this property or method". Ok, so I try commenting out that line and trying deserialize(result). Then exception says "Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON. Parameter name: data".

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to explicitly parse ("deserialize") your JSON! jQuery will try to do this automagically, provided that it can correctly guess the `dataType` returned. You can, of course, specify that you're expecting JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../../Checkout/ChangeAddress',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',               // <========== this line
    traditional: true,
    data: {addressId: sum},
    success: function (result) {

        var json = result.get_data();
        var data = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);

        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

That said - it *is* possible that the XHR is not coming back with valid JSON. Could you perhaps provide an example of the JSON returned to your jQuery `success` callback?

Comment: Ok, I have to laugh. What da'ya know, I can read the Address1 value directly without explicit parse. Being new to MVC I find all this automagic stuff nice, but also a bit disconcerting. Where is the rule book (potion book?) that explains the magic? Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @Adventure: start with http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax, specifically the `dataType` option.